# Most efficient way to create an edit-dialogue that loads through AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have several AJAX APIs that read data from the back-end and most of them have a counterpart for writing back the edited content too.

Examples:

1. `getSalaries / editSalaries`,
2. `getParticipants / editParticipants`,
3. `getPermissions / editPermissions` and a couple more.

Each of the API corresponds to 1 or 2 MySQL tables in the back-end.

To create dialogues for each one of these read-edit-write functionalities, I do not want to write a whole bunch of HTML/JS/jQuery that will be very similar except for some changes in the labels/textbox-IDs.

Is there a way that I can specify a table in JSON format where each cell takes in:

1. The label-name to display,
2. Field in the AJAX's data to populate and
3. A type of HTML control to display

And some UI-library that automatically handles the reading of data from the back-end, filling that data in the dialogue, then reading the edited values and calling the AJAX for writing back to the back-end?

Example: I should be able to specify a table in JSON as:

```
{
   "rows":
   [
       // Row 1
       [
          // Column 1
          {"label": "Participant-name", "ajax-field": "pname", "html-control": "text"},
          // Column 2
          {"label": "Age", "ajax-field": "age", "html-control": "text"},
          // Column 3
          {"label": "Sex", "ajax-field": "sex", "html-control": "option"}
       ],
       // If more than 1 row here, then rows for one entity should be
       // grouped together in a field-set without name.
   ],
   "read-url": "/getParticipants",
   "write-url": "/editParticipants"
}
```

Benefit of such a solution would be that:

1. It is much easier to write JSON than HTML (XML is way too verbose).
2. I do not have to write the code to ajax-read/display and UI-read/ajax-write over and over again.

I think most of my code can fit into tabular format (with Add/Delete/Save/Cancel buttons).

Comment: There are dozens if not hundreds of projects on github that generate form from json schema.

Comment: Robert, most problems usually have several solutions. The reason people ask for help is that they were unable to find a good one themselves. If you have used such a library in the past, it would be of great help to me if you can share some details about the same or recommend some good ones.

Comment: I think you'll find that questions asking for library recommendations get shutdown on SO.  I made the comment because there really is such a glut of resources.